# ¿Cómo puedo comprobar si un equipo que tiene una IP esta encendido o apagado por medio de PHP sin utilizar PING?

Tags: php, html, ping

Tengo un inconveniente el cual me gustaría que me ayudaran a encontrar una mejor solución. Lo que pasa que en mi trabajo tenemos cerca de 40 equipos que están en red las cuales conocemos las IP de cada uno de ellos y estos equipos siempre deben de permanecer encendidos, pero en ocasiones los usuarios apagan los equipos.

Entonces me di a la tarea de realizar una pequeño código e interfaz con PHP y HTML el cual envío un PING cada 3 segundos y si este no responde significa que esta apagado, pero al parecer como son muchos PING al mismo tiempo hace que el wampserver se trabe ya que solo muestra la interfaz 1 minuto y después se ponga la pantalla en blanco.

Les muestro mi código para el PING

```
$output1 = shell_exec("ping -n 1 -w 1 192.168.1.10");

if (strpos($output1, "Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.")) 
{
  echo "El equipo no Responde";
}
else
{
  echo "El Equipo esta en linea";
}
```

Comment: Está interesante tu pregunta. La verdad se me ocurre que lo probaras con nmap, haces un escaneo de tu red y verificas si las ips que necesitas están en ese escaneo. Claro, estoy suponiendo que esos equipos tienen un ip fija dentro de tu red local.

Comment: Otra sería usar `net-tools` y usas `arp` y eso te devolvería una lista de sus dispositivos con nombre de red. Creo que sería otra opción.

Comment: Hola, el tema es que así uses un comando diferente a ping y haces los 40 al mismo tiempo, tal vez el wampp falle nuevamente. Te sugiero optimizar un poco el código, hacer un bucle para que se ejecute cada segundo 5 ips por ejemplo al mismo tiempo, luego las otras 5 y asi sucesivamente.

Comment: O mandar un traza específica de paquetes y verificar la respuesta.

Comment: Fuera de tópico: ¿Haz pensado en solucionarlo a nivel de sistema operativo? Por ejemplo, deshabilitar la opción de apagar el computador mediante reglas en active directory o similar? (o algún equivalente para linux)

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Si tienes la opción de iniciar un conexión remota vía Windows RDC, puedes habilitar el puerto 3389 para todas las PC. Podrías intentar iniciar una sesión de escritorio remoto

```
<?php
$timeout = 10;
$socket = @fsockopen( 'ip-de-la-pc', 3389, $errno, $errstr, $timeout );
$online = ( $socket !== false );

var_dump( $online );
```

El @ es porque fsockopen devuelve un "PHP Warning" en caso de que la conexión no se pueda establecer

3389 es el puerto usado por defecto para crear una conexión remota.

Puedes probar con diferentes valores en `$timeout`

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacer que el ping se ejecute en intervalos controlados, yo personalmente lo uso para mantener viva mi conexión vpn

ejemplo de un archivo .bat en windows

```
@ECHO OFF 
set IPADDRESS=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
set INTERVAL=3 
:PINGINTERVAL 
ping %IPADDRESS% -n 1 >> lista.txt
timeout %INTERVAL% 
GOTO PINGINTERVAL
```

Puedes guardar este código y que tu script lo llame

También puedes ejecutarlo en un modo simplificado y tu código quedaría algo así:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 -n 1 && timeout 5

$output1 = shell_exec("ping -n 1 -w 1 192.168.1.10 && timeout 5");
    if (strpos($output1, "Tiempo de espera agotado para esta solicitud.")) 
     {
          echo "El equipo no Responde";
     }
     else
     {
          echo "El Equipo esta en linea";
     }
```